# O que é CircuitBreaker?

Tags: terminologia, design-pattern, circuitbreaking

Já vi algumas definições sobre [CircuitBreaker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/circuit-breaker), mas ainda não entendi a fundo como usá-lo e tenho minhas duvidas.

Qual o melhor cenário para se aplicado?

O que se deve aborta para ser implementado por completo?

Pode ser empregado em qualquer ambiente?

Quais Framework podem ser usados para facilitar uso com .NET?

Comment: Não conhecia pronto assim, pode ser aplicação em Rx, né?

Comment: Rx ? que isso. @bigown

Comment: Programação reativa.

Comment: @bigown, Sim, estive usando para essa finalidade, ele tem foco na resiliency da programação reativa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que a [explicação do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) é uma das mais fáceis de se entender, com ilustrações e exemplos em código.

---

Imagine um sistema que faz diversas requisições HTTP a um *webservice* remoto. Por um motivo desconhecido, este *webservice* começa a ficar sobrecarregado e as requisições HTTP demoram muito e dão *timeout*.

Seu sistema pode começar a bloquear recursos importantes ao aguardar muitas requisições que por fim vão dar *timeout*.

O objetivo do Circuit Breaker é se posicionar como uma camada antes do recurso real (o *webservice*, neste caso). No nosso exemplo, ele seria capaz de identificar falhas na comunicação com o *webservice* (a partir de uma contagem de falhas externas, por exemplo) e fazer com que sua consulta falhasse o mais rápido possível internamente, evitando o desperdício de recursos.

O Circuit Breaker também tem a capacidade de identificar quando o recurso volta a responder, retornando ao fluxo normal.

---

Então, respondendo às suas perguntas:

> Qual o melhor cenário para se aplicado?

Cenários onde falhar cedo resulta em economia de recursos. No exemplo acima, um sistema altamente dependente de um *webservice* remoto

> O que se deve aborta para ser implementado por completo?

Não sei se entendi corretamente a pergunta... Mas, como vimos acima, qualquer fluxo custoso pode ser abortado.

> Pode ser empregado em qualquer ambiente?

Sim. Mas é necessário avaliar se a complexidade que será adicionada vai compensar no final.

> Quais Framework podem ser usados para facilitar uso com .NET?

A biblioteca [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) oferece várias políticas relacionadas à resiliência, inclusive Circuit Breaker.